# Why does angularjs Digest go into infinite loop with date getter function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a DTO object which has a Date parameter.  I am wrapping this Dto in a view model object the properties of which I am then binding in my view to a label.

```
<label class="form-control">{{controller.ViewModel.Date}}</label>
```

In the view model I have a getter thus. (I am using TypeScript)

```
public get Date(): Date {
    return new Date(Date.parse(this.dto.Date));
    //return moment(this.dto.Date).toDate();
}
```

the emitted JavaScript:

```
Object.defineProperty(ViewModel.prototype, "Date", {
    get: function () {
        return new Date(Date.parse(this.dto.Date));
    },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```

I believe that the reason because I am creating a new Date in the getter and angular thinks that this means the dates are always new and it keeps getting the date until the model stabilises, thus causing an infinite loop.

Why is angular doing this?
Why does it keep calling the getter over and over, what is wrong with just calling it once?
Can I tell angular to just call the getter once and accept the value it is given?

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: angular will run consecutive digests until the result of all watchers stabilize. Here, each time your watcher returns a different object, thus generating the infinite loop. Sometimes you can get around this by using toString() on the result when called from a template. Ex: `{{ controller.ViewModel.Date.toString() }}`

Comment: Why don't you store the result of the function in a $scope variable and then use that in the HTML, instead of directly linking to the function

Answer (score 3):

If you are on a high enough version, you could try a one time binding.
Follow the instructions here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding

You are basically right with your assumption that angular thinks the dates are always new. You are changing the value with the evaluation in your getter and angular's dirty checking and watches triggers another digest.

Could you also try parsing the date ahead of time?

Comment: I tried hiding my operations from angular like this but I get the same result.
        public get TxDate(): Date {

            let dtoDate = moment(this.dto.TxDate).toDate();
            if (this._txDate === undefined || this._txDate === null)
                this._txDate = dtoDate;

            if (dtoDate.getFullYear() != this._txDate.getFullYear() ||
                dtoDate.getMonth() != this._txDate.getMonth() ||
                dtoDate.getDate() != this._txDate.getDate())
            {
                this._txDate = dtoDate;
            }

            return this._txDate;
        }

Answer (score 2):

I found an way round this as follows:

posting only the typescript as it is more readable:

```
 public DisplayDate: string = new Date(Date.parse(this.dto.TxDate)).toLocaleDateString();
    public get TxDate(): Date {

        let txDate = new Date(Date.parse(this.dto.TxDate));
        if (this._txDate === null && this._txDate != txDate)
            this._txDate = txDate;
        return this._txDate;
    }
    public set TxDate(value: Date) {
        this.dto.TxDate = value.toISOString();
        this._txDate = value;
        this.DisplayDate = this._txDate.toLocaleDateString();
    }
    private _txDate: Date = null;
```

This appears to give me what I need.  The Display date is bound to a visible label so that I can get the display format I want and the TxDate is bound to a hidden form date-picker control This way it all seems to work. And I can keep my Dto date in ISO8601 format.